# LeafletJs GeoMan Polygon Edit

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-geoman

When i create a new Polygon, on "PM:DRAWSTART" i initialize event "pm:vertexadded"

It's allow me to detect if:

- New point is inside an existing polygons, so i remove it. *
- If last line created intersect with an existing polygons ( TurfJS lineIntersect ), i remove it.
- If last line created "kinks" ( TurfJS also ) , i remove it.
- I use : "map.pm.Draw["Polygon"]._removeLastVertex();" to remove last point.

My problem.

When polygon is closed (last point click on first one) "PM:DRAWEND" event is executed. 
So in this case i'm not able to check if the new polygon is overlaping an existing one as i do with event "pm:vertexadded".

Is it possible on event "PM:CREATE" if the new polygon is overlaping an existing one to go in edit mode 
( polygon.toggleEdit() ) and go back on stage as i don't click on the last point to close the polygon.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can reinit the draw polygon with the existing latlngs:

```
map.on('pm:create',function (e) {
  e.layer.removeFrom(map);
  setTimeout(function (){ //Needed because snapping
    map.pm.enableDraw('Polygon');
    var latlngs = e.layer.getLatLngs();
    if(!L.LineUtil.isFlat(latlngs)){
      latlngs = latlngs[0];
    }
    latlngs.forEach(function (latlng) {
      map.pm.Draw.Polygon._createVertex({latlng: latlng})
    })
  },100);
})
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/omw2pt34/
draw a polygon